# Spring MVC vs Struts 2 - Front Controller vs Filter

Tags: java, spring-mvc, архитектура, struts

Господа,

недавно углубился в сравнительное изучение двух замечательных Java Web frameworks - Spring MVC и Struts 2

Обратили на себя внимание следующие особенности реализации.

За диспетчеризацию вызовов (надеюсь, я использую верный термин) в Spring MVC отвечает сервлет: `DispatcherServlet`. Который в умных статьях именуют Front Controller.

Та же роль в Struts 2 отведена `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`.

С чем это связано: почему в одном случае сервлет, в другом - фильтр?

И можно ли (когда это востребовано), помимо `DispatcherServlet` и `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`, включать в цепь обработки другие сервлеты?

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот, почему сервлет, почему фильтр. Особенности реализации такие, только вот друг с другом они не связанные. Трудно представить себе конструкцию в которой два кирпича лежат в одном месте, так же и в веб приложении нельзя использовать фреймворки которые делают одно и тоже.

Другие сервлеты использовать можно, но в этом нет необходимости если используется фреймворк. В противном случае приходится исключать из маппинга эти сервлеты.